# How to return from a function completely in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form, in which contains a number of input fields. When the user click the submit button, I would like to validate the user input. Because this form (suppose it's alike a resume) could contains a few similar field, such as year, school, diploma, etc. So I use JQuery **attribute selector** to choose these similar fields and use JQuery **each** function to iterate them for validation. My code is like below.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
            $('input[name="education_year[]"]').each(function(){
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    alert("education year is empty !");
                    return;
                }
            });

            $('input[name="diploma[]"]').each(function(){
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    alert("diploma field is empty");
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
```

because the user may leave several fields empty, so i want my code gives out only one alert. However, in the code above, the **return** keyword doesn't help. It seems to me that it is more like a **break** statement to exit the **each** function. Can anyone tell me how to end the **click** function ?

Comment: I'd highly recommend taking a look at jQuery validate to help with this - http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: will you be able to create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RussCam I was trying to use that plugin, but found some difficulties.  So finally I gave it up for the moment.....

Comment: @EnsomHodder I would also recommend using the valiation plugin it is very is to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    var valid = true;
    $('input[name="education_year[]"]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("education year is empty !");
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!valid){
        return;
    }

    $('input[name="diploma[]"]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("diploma field is empty");
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yep, I also thought of using a flag variable, but I am wondering doesn't Jquery provide a more elegant way to do it ? If not, I will use this solution. :)

Comment: @EnsomHodder because when you use a `each callback` and return you are returning from the anonymous function not from the click callback method

Answer (score 1):

`return` in your code will simply stop execution of the current iteration in the loop and move to the next. You need to store a variable containing the state of your validation and check that. Try this:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    var isValid = true;

    $('input[name="education_year[]"]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val() && isValid) {
            alert("education year is empty !");
            isValid = false;
        }
    });

    $('input[name="diploma[]"]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val() && isValid) {
            alert("diploma field is empty");
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return true; or return false; on a submit to choose whether or not the submit continues after your logic.